# xD card is really slow to read in Mac OS 10.6.4

Tags: mac, photos.app, camera

I am having a bit of a problem transferring pictures off my Olympus 850SW digital camera (maybe it being pink has something to do with it).

#### When using the camera

When connecting the camera to the computer I chose PC>MTP and iPhoto opens and starts indexing thumbnails. It would sit there (iPhoto says "Loading Photos...") and nothing has happened. The LED on the camera is still flashing.

If I chose PC>Storage then the computer does not react at all.

#### When using a card reader.

If I use an xD card reader similar thing happens. Doing import from iPhoto takes ages for one photo, browsing the car in Finder is equally slow. I can actually transfer files but it's painfully slow - takes about 6 minutes to transfer 50 MB.

What can I do to fix this issue? It strikes me as a system issue (i.e. OS dealing with the memory card), rather than the camera or the card reader.

#### When using either camera or reader with a PC

Both work fine and photos get transferred pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening “Image Capture” and see if it works from there? I’ve had similar problems in the past with my Kodak.

Comment: I gave Image Capture a go and got a similar issue. Too slow to be usable, when trying to import got an error saying images could not be transferred.